# I can't get Google Adwords Customers Campagin inform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-ads-api

I want to build a web application. Clients can use the web application to read their google Adwrods accounts information( campagins or budgets ).

First, I use oath2 get client's refresh_token and access_token.
Using the refresh_token, I can get all adwords id under the client by (https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby)

```
client = Google::Ads::GoogleAds::GoogleAdsClient.new do |config|
  config.client_id = "client_id"
  config.client_secret = "client_secret"
  config.refresh_token = "refresh_token"
  config.login_customer_id = "XXX-XXX-XXXX"
  config.developer_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end
accessible_customers = client.service.customer.list_accessible_customers().resource_names
```

When I want to get client Adword account information,

```
resource_name = client.path.customer("XXXXXXXX")
customer = client.service.customer.get_customer(resource_name: resource_name)
```

I get "GRPC::Unauthenticated: 16:Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential", but the config file can't let me set access_token.

So, where can i set client's access_token, or which step i missed?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include more code, show us the whole file where you are setting `client` and calling `client.service.customer`

Comment: Hahah, I think SO, it means finallyXDDD
The above is all my client config setting. 
The login_customer_id is my adwords manager account id, developer_token is the manager account's developer_token, and refresh_token is got by client auth.
And I just called the  ```client.service.customer``` when i got the customer_id, is there method i called before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that `client` has not been set up correctly. It could be a bunch of issues from Google account to wrong information. I would check and make sure all the info you are passing in `Google::Ads::GoogleAds::GoogleAdsClient.new` is correct.

Also, you only need to pass 'login_customer_id' for manager accounts only, it doesn't sound like you are a manager account.

From https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby/blob/master/google_ads_config.rb

```
  # Required for manager accounts only: Specify the login customer ID used to
  # authenticate API calls. This will be the customer ID of the authenticated
  # manager account. If you need to use different values for this field, then
  # make sure fetch a new copy of the service after each time you change the
  # value.
  # c.login_customer_id = 'INSERT_LOGIN_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE'
```

Comment: Hi @nzajt , I passed my adwords manager account id to the login_customer_id, didn't it?

Comment: By the way, my developer_token is my adwords manager account's developer_token